# Google benchmark does not write to output file

Tags: google-benchmark

I am using google benchmark to test performances of two algorithms. However, `benchmark_out` command seems to not work for me.

1) flags `--benchmart_out=/home/knn.json --benchmark_format=json` give error `invalid file name: '/home/knn.json`

2) flags `--benchmart_out=./knn.json --benchmark_format=json` successfully runs the benchmark with console log but does not create `.json`.

Is there anything wrong with the flag input given?

Comment: Is that a typo in the question? Was your command using `--benchmark_out` or `--benchmart_out` as you've written?

Comment: Also, note that the output file will use the `--benchmark_out_format` format rather than the `--benchmark_format` which is used for the console output.